# Проблема с видео драйверами при обновлении Windows до 1903

Tags: windows

После обновления Windows до 1903 слетают драйвера с видеокарты и становятся стандартные майкрософта. При установке с оф. сайта, драйвера устанавливаются, но видеокарта их то ли не видит, то ли не хочет подхватывать. GF 1050 TI. Удаление тоже не помогает, сразу по умолчанию становятся майкрософта. Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Есть решение?

Comment: Лучше задать подобный вопрос саппорту Microsoft. Так как проблема специфическая, к примеру у меня нормально всё обновилось на 10 Pro, с Nvidia 1060 на борту, драйвер 430-й стоит

Answer (score 0):

Сегодня обновилась сама винда, все прошло без проблем. Видимо пофиксили. Всем спасибо, вопрос закрыт.